Change label Color on Date Picker Swift UI

So I want to change my Date picker (WheelDatePickerStyle) label color, currently default is green i want to change to yellow already tried several properties like accentColor but didnt work.
Thanks
Heres my code:
DatePicker(
    "Start Date",
    selection: $date,
    in: dateRange,
    displayedComponents: [.date]
).datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())


I don´t think there is a specific API for styling the highlight color. But you can try to use hueRotation.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var date = Date.now
    var body: some View {
        DatePicker("", selection: $date, displayedComponents: .hourMinuteAndSecond)
            .hueRotation(Angle(degrees: 270))            
    }
}

Output:

